# using protobuf in java without having C++ installation on the machine

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers

I am a java guys and I dont have C++ installed on my computer (win 7). Is there some way I can generate Protos files(builder and message classes) without installing protoc compiler.

Comment: What is your operation system?

Comment: @WeiboLi I am using Windows7. I was expecting a simple jar that could interpret a proto file and generate the Java files. I dont understand the boundation to C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to install C++ or protoc compiler on your win 7. Just download the zip package for Windows platform from google code [protoc-2.5.0-win32.zip](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/detail?name=protoc-2.5.0-win32.zip&can=2&q=) . There is a `protoc.exe` in the zip file. It already built, so your don't need to build the protoc compiler yourself. Just use it in windows command line.

Comment: ahh ..I simply downloaded their package with the sources and didnt find the exe. Stupid of me. Thanks

Comment: There is no **protoc.exe**!